# Landscape mode: why do I get different result on my computer screen and different on my phone?

Tags: java, android

This is the first time I'm making an activity xml in landscape model. Until now, what I saw on my computer screen that was what I got on my phone. Now, it's not even close! I placed some layouts, buttons and stuff, centered them like I need them, and tried on the phone and some stuff are way off the screen, some stuff are moved to the right, nothing is like I made it in my xml. So I have to move some stuff a little, then try it on my phone, without any order or rule. Why is this happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundland" >


   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bA1"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="A1" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bA2"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="A2" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bA3"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="A3" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bA4"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="A4" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bKolonaA"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="Kolona A" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

             <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bB1"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="B1" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bB2"
                   android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="B2" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bB3"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="B3" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bB4"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="B4" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bKolonaB"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="Kolona B" />   
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bC1"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="C1" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bC2"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="C2" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bC3"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="C3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bC4"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="C4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bKolonaC"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="Kolona C" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bD1"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="D1" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bD2"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="D2" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bD3"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="D3" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bD4"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="D4" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bKolonaD"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="Kolona D" />
            </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bIzlazA"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttons_final"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="280dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bKonacno"
                        android:layout_width="260dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttons_final"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvVreme"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: impossible without some code

Comment: OK, i edit my post. But, I don't think the code is the problem. On picture you can see that I needed to move the bottom center button (the big one) all the way to the left, to make it look center on my phone. The right TextView should be all the way right (like the small button is on the left).

Comment: u making it for only landscape or u supporting both land and port??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i know is that the emulator doesn't work same as real devices so why don't you us your phone in debug mode to see what your code really do.

post your code may be we can see if it's not the emulator problem

**EDIT:**

just add android:layoutweight="1" to the 3 lyouts at the bottom 
you should have better results :)

```
<LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bIzlazA"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="280dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bKonacno"
                        android:layout_width="260dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvVreme"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't use emulator at all, I try my code on my phone every time.

Comment: I just deployer this lyout on my samsung tablet and i have no problems .

can you post the other picture you get which  is diffrent form the one already posted

Comment: OK, it will take me 10 or 15 minutes to make it.

Comment: have you put the eclipse tool in landscape mode too?

Comment: It was faster than i thought. :) What do you mean? These pics are taken from Eclipse, not emulator. You can see that on 3rd pic.

Comment: On the second pic is the example how it SHOULD be, but if I create it like this, the textview will not be visible on my phone, it will be somewhere right off the phone, and the big center button will be all the way right, partly visible.

Comment: Yes, this actually is better. What was the problem??

Comment: for me I had no problem like you describe the pc screen is exactly what i see on device but your code specify layouts widths and the parent layout just put them (as it should ) one after the other the layout weight 1,1,1 just resize the layouts to 33%,33%,33% of their parent linear layout size

Answer (score 0):

Probably different resolutions on emulator and on device, and you didn't used dpi but pixels.

Also it can be a problem when using absolute layout.

Hard to gues without the code

Comment: I always use dp's. Sp's only for text. You can see the code above.